# How to retrieve even indices from a vector and divide them by two using R in one line?

Tags: r, vector, rstudio

The problem I face is:

Using the vector x below, divide every element in an even index by two, without modifying the elements in odd indices.

The vector is:

```
x <- 1:10
```

Answer (score 1):

Since dividing by 1 is the same as doing nothing, you could just rely on vector recycling and do:

```
x / 1:2
#[1] 1 1 3 2 5 3 7 4 9 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]/2
```

Or maybe:

```
x[seq(2, length(x), 2)] <- x[seq(2, length(x), 2)]/2
```